# How to remove time in date inside a datatable?

Tags: javascript, datatable

I have a datatable and a column that has date in it. The problem is there is a time showing too. I don't know how to remove it

I tried this

```
var grid = $('#grid').DataTable({
              
                format: 'D-M-Y',
            });
```

it did not remove the time

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please refer official docs for Datatable. There are lot of ways in which this can be done. If you still faced the issue, post the minimal reproducible problem showing code of what you have tried.

Comment: Hello, I just checked the docs for datatable and I now know how to fix it. Thank you for referring it. I will now post the answer

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to **CodeThing** I have fixed it by using this

```
 var grid = $('#grid').DataTable({
           
            columnDefs: [
       {
           targets: 2, //2 is where my column date is at
           render: DataTable.render.date(),
       },
            ],
        });
```